# Floating Point Numeric - SAS decimal issue

Tags: floating-point, sas, numeric

Does anybody know what SAS format is needed in order to convert this string correctly?

```
data _null_;
 x="0.14553821459";
 y=input(x,best32.);
 put y=;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
data _null_;
 x="0.14553821459";
 y=input(x,13.11);
 put y= 13.11;
run;
```

I got

```
y=0.14553821459
```

Comment: aah - interesting - never seen a format used on a put statement like that.  I see the problem was not the conversion format but the format of the variable being created (Y in this case).  Thankyou..

Comment: You really don't want to use a decimal part on an informat, unless you really want to tell SAS where to place the implied decimal point when the string being converted does not have one. Otherwise any string that represents an integer will be divided by the provided power of 10.